# Detect change in NSManagedObjectContext in app delegate from different class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios6, appdelegate

I have an `NSManagedObjectContext` in my `app delegate` and data is loaded and saved fine. I also call `NSManagedObjectContext` from master view controller and load data there. However I have problem as when new data is saved to `NSManagedObjectContext` I don't know how to detect change and reload table in master view controller. I am guessing I could use `NSNotification` but is it possible to use `NSNotification` in master view controller for `NSManagedObjectContext` in app delegate?

I tried to implement this code where context is the `NSManagedObjectContext` from the app delegate (this won't work obviously). Any suggestions on how detect the change in data?

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(handleDidSaveNotification:)
            name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
          object:context];

    if (![context save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"there is a change");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the view controller should be using the managed object context as created by the app delegate (for the main thread). If the app delegate is doing some significant data loading then is should create another managed object context specifically for that purpose and on a background thread.

If you can, your view controller should use `NSFetchedResultsController` to source data from the managed object context. It provides an easy mechanism for getting only the data required to be displayed and (if you make the view controller the FRC delegate) it will also monitor changes to the managed object context and tell you when the table view needs to be reloaded.

If you can't use a `NSFetchedResultsController`, then your notification method should work fine. The code you show above will add `self` (which I'm assuming is the view controller) as an observer. You should do this when the view is loaded and then `handleDidSaveNotification:` will be called when you need to reload the table view. Remember to remove yourself as an observer when the view is unloaded and when the view controller is deallocated.

From your comment, you say:

> I use NSFetchedResultsController and this data is loaded into array which populates table

Don't do that... Use the `NSFetchedResultsController` to get the data, but don't copy it into an array - that destroys most of the benefit of the `NSFetchedResultsController`. Instead:

1. Make yourself the delegate of the `NSFetchedResultsController` and in `controllerDidChangeContent:` you just need to `[self.tableView reloadData];`.
2. In your table view delegate method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, use the `NSFetchedResultsController` to get the object whose data will be displayed on the cell using `objectAtIndexPath:`.

Please read the Ray Wenderlich `NSFetchedResultsController` guide [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller).

Comment: I use NSFetchedResultsController and this data is loaded into array which populates table. I also use delegate to access instance of NSManagedObjectContext in app delegate. Problem is data is fetched when view is loaded but where should I put consequent request for new data when it's reloaded?